# Converting LyX Nomenclature to Glossaries

Tags: lyx, glossaries, nomenclature

I would like to add a nomenclature to my LyX document. Currently LyX only supports the [nomencl package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl). However, since this package has not been updated since 2005 I would like to use the [glossaries package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

I think it should be possible to create a workaround, much like the [Biblatex workaround in Lyx](http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex). I would this this would looks something like this:

1. Add a LyX nomenclature
2. Encapsulate the nomenclature `item` in a LyX comment
3. Call the glossaries package in the document preamble
4. Since there is no compatibility option in glossaries, redefine the commands like `\let\nomenclCommand\glossariesCommand`

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

I already came across the same problem a couple of times and ended up using Nicola Talbot's package [glossaries](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), too. The only dissatifactory part about it was, that there is no native support by LyX to support glossaries. I tried to send a feature request to the LyX development team to enable LyX users to maintain the database files that are used to compose glossaries. If it was possible to edit these database files with LyX it should not be too hard to let LyX guarantee the databases to be free from duplicates for example.

I did not succeed in convincing myself of any workaround being worth the time for its implementation. Therefore I was still having to maintain ordinary text files with ordinary text editors in combination with using LyX for the document's general markup.

Comment: Did LyX team reply you? I mean if either `nomencl` or LyX is going to update, probably we can just wait. But if not...